# Call python method from java

Tags: java, python, jython

I try to call a python method from java, and made a very simple example. But I have an exception:

My py file (test.py)

```
def tmp():
    return "test!!!!!"
```

My java code

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.exec("import test");
PyObject someFunc = interpreter.get("tmp");
System.out.println(someFunc);
PyObject result = someFunc.__call__();
String realResult = (String) result.__tojava__(String.class);
System.out.println(realResult);
```

And I have this result, exception on line *PyObject result = someFunc.__call__();*, because someFunc is null

```
null 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException   at
  com.testing.Test.test(Test.java:936)  at
  com.testing.Test.main(Test.java:96)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Use `interpreter.get("test.tmp");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interpreter.exec("from test import tmp");
PyObject someFunc = interpreter.get("tmp");
```